# Embedding content within a UserControl instance

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF UserControl, which is simply a Label for whatever else it goes with.  E.g, a Label for a TextBox.  I want to place this TextBox inside the LabeledControl markup, like this:

```
<LabeledControl Label="First name">
  <TextBox Binding="{FirstName}" />
</LabeledControl>
```

The reason I want to do this is to style the way controls and their labels look.

I can't find an obvious way to do this.  Am I even approaching this the right way?  Should I be looking at templates instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that a better option would be to use the built-in `HeaderedContentControl`, which allows you to specify a `Header` (your label) and a `Content` (your text box) property.

You can then specify a `ControlTemplate` for the `HeaderedContentControl` to alter the appearance:

```
<Style x:Key="MyLabelledItemStyle" TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="2" />
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This example just concatenates the two components horizontally in a `StackPanel`, but you could do something more complicated if required.

You can then use this in XAML as below:

```
<HeaderedContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyLabelledItemStyle}" Header="First Name">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
</HeaderedContentControl>
```